# 'Text could not be created' error running three.js example on Edge with WebGL context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, webgl, microsoft-edge

Running `three.js` on Edge displays 'text could not be created. Reason: Could not create a WebGL context

I tried running the official `three.js` example on Edge, but I encountered an error stating 'text could not be created. Reason: Could not create a WebGL context.' However, it runs fine on Chrome. I have tried various solutions, but I couldn't resolve the issue. I am using Edge version 113.0.1774.50 (Official Build) (arm64) on Mac. Please help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the official doc you mentioned? Based on this error message, I found some related issues. Did you manually enable `Choose ANGLE graphics backend` in `Edge://flags`?

Comment: The selected option is Default. I tried the OpenGL and Metal options, but they didn't work.

Comment: I have tested this on Mac OS (both intel and arm64 build) with Microsoft Edge 113.0.1774.50, and they all work fine. You can try to disable the extensions or reset Edge, or you can  try to reset devtools preferences settings(Press `F12` -> `F1` -> scroll down to bottom -> `reset default...`). Otherwise I think you have to reinstall the Edge.